# some Question About dark mode from android

Tags: android, darkmode

When I use

```
AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
```

to open & close dark mode. then i test using my phone's dark mode Button(not my app code), then my APP isn't changing.

why? How can I do?

MY phone is android 9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from what i understand in your question, what you're looking for is:

[MODE_NIGHT_FOLLOW_SYSTEM](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/app/AppCompatDelegate#MODE_NIGHT_FOLLOW_SYSTEM)

when you're using `MODE_NIGHT_YES` or `MODE_NIGHT_NO` it forces those onto your application, but you need to use `MODE_NIGHT_FOLLOW_SYSTEM` if you want to follow what the device is using

Comment: thank you for your reply. But I mainly use MODE_NIGHT_YES to make changes, and then make changes through the system, but there is no change, the app must be restarted to change

Comment: i'm not sure how else to answer your, what you're doing won't work because you app doesn't know that anything has changed